# What do you call such a relation between subsets in a poset

Tags: terminology, order-theory, posets, gm.general-mathematics

Consider a poset $(X, \geq)$. Let's define a new relation $\succsim$ on subsets of $X$: for $A, B\subseteq X$, say $A\succsim B$ if for any $a\in A$ and any $b\in B$, we have $a\geq b$.

Does such a relation already have a name? Note that the relation is not a preorder (reflexivity fails).

Comment: In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07801 we used the notation $B\angle A$ for this,  but I have not seen that anywhere else.  Note that $A\angle\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\angle B$ for vacuous reasons, so transitivity fails as well as reflexivity.

Comment: @NeilStrickland do you mind explaining why $A\angle\emptyset$? Wouldn't that depend on the initial order on $X$?

Comment: To say that $A\angle\emptyset$ means that for all $a\in A$ and $b\in\emptyset$ we have $a\leq b$.  But there are no possible cases for $b$, so this is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: I would just say that it is an _induced relation_, although not an induced order, and although _induced_ may have other meanings. You may also call it a _derived relation_, but there is a risk of confusion with derivatives. Do you need more? May you please explain why? It may help providing better answers.

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy I am comparing the relation in question to the strong-set order (SSO). I am wondering if it has a commonly used name, so that I avoid confusion for the reader.